# Elasticsearch delete a list of indices with the Javascript client failing with "No Living connections"

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-indices

I am using the official Elasticsearch Javascript client with version **6.0** and trying to delete a list of indices.

The code is:

```
const client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    "hosts": [
        "https://the-es-host-here.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "apiVersion": "6.0",
    "sniffOnStart": true
});

const indices = [
    'enduser-2017-12-04',
    'enduser-2017-12-08',
    'enduser-2017-12-07',
    'enduser-2017-12-01',
    'enduser-2017-12-14',
    'enduser-2017-12-10',
    'enduser-2017-12-27',
    'enduser-2017-12-02',
    'enduser-2017-12-18',
    'enduser-2017-12-22',
    'enduser-2017-12-28',
    'enduser-2017-12-09',
    'enduser-2017-12-03',
    'enduser-2017-12-05',
    'enduser-2017-12-11',
    'enduser-2017-11-29',
    'enduser-2017-12-17',
    'enduser-2017-12-15',
    'enduser-2017-12-19'
];

client.indices.delete({
    index: indices
}, (error) => {
    if(error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

But none of the indexes are being deleted and I am seeing the following error:

```
Error: No Living connections
```

I don't see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Does `curl "https://the-es-host-here.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com"` return anything? To make sure that elasticsearch is running on the host.

Answer (score 0):

After an hour of fiddling the problem was related to passing `"sniffOnStart": true` into `new elasticsearch.Client()`. I have no idea why this breaks, but after removing `sniffOnStart` everything works.